# Menus and sub Menus problem?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS Style Sheet

In my web page, i have two class like menu and leftside. In menu i have the ul, li classes. i want to use a ul, li in left side also, but the problem is if i used the ul, li, it was matching with menu ul, li

ul -underlist, li - list

I tried to change the code of sheet,

my css code.

```
#leftside{
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

a:hover {

    text-decoration: underline;
    color: maroon;
}

ul {
    padding: 10px 10px 2px 0;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

li li {

    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #BDBDBD;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat left 50%;
}
```

Html Code

```
<li>                    
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Enquiry</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Location Map</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

ul, list are matching with the menu ul, li

How to solve this issue. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduse the amount of space above the inner list change the padding for the ul so that it is 0 or negative.

For Example:

```
ul {
    padding: 0 10px 2px 0;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

You can also use a special style sheet to correct the problem in Internet Explorer by doing something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You would then need a second CSS file named iespecific.css which has the above ul styling in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an id to distinguish between the two.

For example the HTML would be:

```
<ul id="outter">
<li>The Outter List</li>
<li>More Outter List                    
  <ul id="inner">
   <li>This is the inner list</li>
   <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Enquiry</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Location Map</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Still The Outter</li>
</ul>
```

In the CSS you would have something like this:

```
#outter ul {
   padding: 10px 10px 2px 0;
   list-style: none;
}
#outter li {
   margin-left: 10px;
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-left: 15px;
}
#inner ul  {
   padding: 10px 10px 2px 15px;
   list-style: none;
}
#inner li {
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   line-height: 30px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   border-bottom: 1px dashed #BDBDBD;
   background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat left 50%;
}
```

This looks something like this:

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2376/examplesg.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2376/examplesg.png)

Comment: @Josh, Thanks, But the problem is i am getting more space on the top of the menus. i adjusted the padding also, still it was showing more space on the top. how to remove the space on the top of the menu.

Comment: You will have to reduce the size of padding or margins. You may even need a negative number. But with out an image of your problem im cant tell you more.

Comment: In firefox, it was showing less space on the top of the menu, but in explorer, it was showing more space on the top of the menu. How to remove the space on the top of the menu. Please